# base64_decode image or pdf is failing in PHP when size is higher than 500kb

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, base64, file-put-contents

I'm uploading files (image or pdf) using AJAX. My process is converting the file to base64 then send the data via AJAX then process in server side (PHP) to become a image or pdf. This is my code in server side and it's working fine but failing when file size is above 500kb.

```
if ($picture_ext == 'pdf') { //pdf                      
    $image_generated_name = $select_name . '_' . $generate_rand_num . '_file.pdf';                      
    file_put_contents(WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/plugin_name/uploads/'.$image_generated_name, base64_decode(substr($product_img_upload,28)));
} else { //image    
    file_put_contents(WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/plugin_name/uploads/'.$image_generated_name, base64_decode(substr($product_img_upload,22)));  
}
```

Comment: failing with what message? you could be going above your server's memory limit for PHP.

Comment: actually i don't know. but i already updated the memory in the php.ini.

Comment: find what the error is... always your step 1. check your web server logs if it's not displaying on the page itself.

Comment: just updated the server configuration and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We dont know what the error is, but I suspect its possibly with your in variables `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`. You can modifiy these in `php.ini` config, 
Add the following commands before that is run, see if it works, and modify your ini based on that:

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
```